# How can I display the caret in an (initially) empty Silverlight DatePickerTextBox?

Tags: silverlight, datepicker

If the `TextBox` of a Silverlight `DatePicker` already contains a date and it gets the focus a caret will be shown. But as long as the `DatePicker`'s `TextBox` is empty, no caret is displayed. How can I get the `DatePicker` to show the caret in its empty `TextBox` when focused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a way to do what I initially asked, I added an animation to hide the watermark in the `Focused` visual state so that the user has at least (a little) visual feedback that the control just got editable.